# Python server does not receive complete string from java client

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp, server

I have a Python server and a java client. when a string is sent from java to python, it's not complete. Example:

Java Code Sending: `Helloooooooooo`

Recieved in Python as:

```
he

lloooooooo

oo
```

here are the codes

Python server:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ("localhost", 10000)
print 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(5)

while True:
     print 'waiting for a connection'
     connection, client_address = sock.accept()

     try:
         print 'connection from', client_address

         while True:
             data = connection.recv(1024)
             print 'received: ' + data
             print type(data)
             if data:
                 print 'sending data back to the client'
                 connection.sendall(data)
             else:
                 print 'no more data from', client_address
                 break

     finally:
         connection.close()
```

Java Client:

```
package server;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Reciever_test {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10000);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while(true)
    {
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
    }

    //clientSocket.close();
}
```

}

Comment: To clarify, do you want the python side to print the whole string at once, and not parts of it?

Comment: yes, exactly. I want the whole string because I am gonna use it later as identifier for which operation I will use

Comment: Then you have to collect the data from the socket until it is complete, maybe until is contains `\n`.

Comment: yes, but i was searching if there is a direct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Client:
Just changed the way i send data to server.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;
    BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 10000);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true)
    {


        while (true) {
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            out.print(input);
            out.flush();
            modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
        }
    }
```

Python Server:
The way I respond had to be changed too(using send instead of sendall)

```
while True:
print 'waiting for a connection'
connection, client_address = sock.accept()

try:
    print 'connection from', client_address

    while True:
        data = connection.recv(4096)
        print data
        print type(data)
        if data:
            print 'sending data back to the client'
            connection.send(data + "\n")
        else:
            print 'no more data from', client_address
            break

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In vain of what Klaus D.is saying, the **recv** guarantees how much data at most it will wait for, it might decide to handle what it has before the size is reached. I used a simple **buffer**, although I am sure there might be better ways:

```
import socket
import atexit

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ("localhost", 10000)
print ('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(5)

def close(connection):
    connection.close()

while True:
     print ('waiting for a connection')
     connection, client_address = sock.accept()
     atexit.register(close, connection)

     try:
         print ('connection from', client_address)

         buffer=[]
         while True:

             data = connection.recv(1024)
             for b in data:
                buffer.append(b)
             print ('received: ' + str(data))
             print (type(data))

             if str(buffer[-1]) == '\n': #if changed to use the buffer to decide when done receiving, the newline is the terminator
                 print ('sending data back to the client')
                 connection.sendall(''.join(buffer))
                 buffer = []
             # else:
             #     print ('no more data from', client_address)
             #     break

     finally:
         close(connection)
```

The **atexit** is to close the socket gracefully in case your program crashes